# Unable to configure the SSL certificate on Apache Windows

Tags: windows, ssl, apache-2.4, configuration

I purchased a certificate from Godaddy, and i received a .crt file along with .p7b file (PKCS#7).

And here is my configuration under https-ssl.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
----
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA
SSLCertificateFile "conf/extra/blablabla.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile "conf/extra/gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b"
```

When i try to start Apache server, i receive the following errors in error log:

- SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/blablabla.crt),
- AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key

I am under Windows Server 2012 environment, with Xampp Apache 2.4 installed. Can anyone let me know what is causing the issue with the SSL configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently blablabla.crt contains the privatekey (which is permitted though not recommended) and the key is encrypted and thus requires a password (which apparently doesn't work on Windows; see for example https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a90/i-get-error-message-error-init-sslpassphrasedialog-builtin-is-not-supported-on-win32.aspx )

Extract the privatekey and decrypt it (unless you already have it e.g. from the CSR generation step) and put the decrypted version back in the file, or remove it from that file and put/leave the decrypted version in a separate file (named something meaningful like blablabla.key) and specify it in `SSLCertificateKeyFile`. In either case for security make sure the ACL on the file containing the decrypted key is as restrictive as possible. With recent OpenSSL (1.0.0+) you can decrypt with one of

```
openssl pkey <oldkey >newkey # no -passout, optional -passin
openssl rsa <oldkey >newkey # ditto, only if key is RSA --
# however without greater knowledge you are unlikely to have 
# successsfully generated a key and obtained a cert for non-RSA

# oldkey can be the blablabla.crt that contains _both_ cert and key;
# OpenSSL will select the correct-type block from a PEM-format file.
```

For OpenSSL 0.9.x instead of `pkey` use

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt <oldkey >newkey
```

However, Apache (via OpenSSL) does not support p7b format for certificate chains, although 2.4.8+ should support chain certs in `SSLCertificateFile` without separate `SSLCertificateChainFile`. First do

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs <chain.p7b >chain.pem
```

then either use that new file as `SSLCertificateChainFile` or append it to the file you are using as `SSLCertificateFile` namely blablabla.crt .

PS: I assume XAMPP (which I don't use myself) gives you openssl commandline. If not, there's a good Windows build of OpenSSL (free) at http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: I don't have the private key. I was only given the .crt and .p7b files. Can i extract the private key from .crt file? If so, how to do that ?

Comment: If Apache is trying to decrypt the privatekey it must be there. Look in the blablabla.crt file for a block of lines beginning with `-----BEGIN [ENCRYPTED|RSA|other] PRIVATE KEY-----` (in the latter cases followed by lines beginning Proc-Type and DEK-Info) and ending with `-----END [same] PRIVATE KEY-----`. Although naming such a file .crt is arguably misleading, some combinations of PEM data like this are allowed. As I said, `openssl` commandline operations like `pkey` and `rsa` will automatically select the privatekey portion of a combined PEM file.

Comment: I have only -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- as the starting and ending lines in the .crt file. I am not sure whether the private key was mapped to the .crt file.

Comment: That's very odd because if I configure my Apache 2.4 (on Ubuntu) with no `SSLCertificateKeyFile` and no key in the cert file, I get the quite logical `AH02203 Init: Private key not found` (plus some stale-looking ASN1 errors) not `AH02564` as you have and which certainly seems to state it found a key that looks encrypted. You must have had a privatekey when you generated the CSR you sent to the CA (GoDaddy); try to remember what you did with it.

Comment: How can i extract the private key? Is there any openssl command for this?

Comment: _If_ PEM file contains privatekey, as I said `pkey` or `rsa` selects it. But you say it isn't in the file, and no command can extract something that isn't there. If you mean can the privatekey be derived from the certificate, absolutely not; the whole point of PKC is that you can publish the publickey (as a cert) because the publickey/cert does not enable recovery of the privatekey. As I added, you could not have obtained a cert from a CA like GoDaddy without having the privatekey, normally by generating it typically `genrsa`; _what did you do with it_?

Comment: Sorry dave, i remember that when i created a CSR and sent it to godaddy, i did not create any private key first. Is that the step i missed out? But still, i received cert files from GoDaddy (blablabla.crt, gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt), because they just needed the .csr file from us.

Comment: Ok, i got it. The private key file was created in my system, when i generated the CSR file. I just missed to look properly in the folder path for the key file. Once i specified the key file along with the .crt file in the Apache SSL configuration file, it worked like a charm. Thanks!